# How to remove Schlage knob / handle

Tags: doors, lock, removal, doorknob

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to remove the door knob/handle pictured below. I've poked in just about every hole I can find to look for a release mechanism on both the handle and knob sides. Nothing has worked. It's corroded as hell, so I'm not sure if that's the issue or not.

Any thoughts?

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

there's a little button on the underside of the stem on the insecure side. press it in with a nail or similar pointed tool and pull on the handle.